# EF Core not using locally cached versions of entities

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a simple query, looks like this:

```cs
await _sharedContext
    .Set<SomeEntityType>()
    .Where(u => u.SomeId == status.SomeOtherField)
    .SingleAsync(cancel)
```

As the name suggests, `_sharedContext` is used consistently throughout the process.

However, a database query is executed against the server each time this code runs.

Usually I'm fighting the cache - I want fresh copies! In this case, I *want* the cache to kick in.

Why isn't it?

Comment: (Person who voted to close with "Needs details or clarity" - please let me know what further info you need.)

Comment: What makes you think EF Core would cache queries by default? If you do want to implement caching, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#example-advanced-command-interception-for-caching for some ideas.